# Swift - Generic function parameter

Tags: swift, xcode, generics, swift-protocols

I am trying to do this:

```
protocol Fly {
}

class Bird: Fly {
}

func fetch<T: Fly>(model: T) {
    print("Done")
}

let bird: Fly = Bird()
fetch(model: bird)
```

However I get this error:

> Cannot invoke 'fetch' with an argument list of type '(model: Fly)'

I set `let bird: Fly = Bird()` to be of type `Fly`, shouldn't it work since the function `fetch` takes any object that conforms to that protocol?

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you are using protocol the syntax to do this is `func fetch<T>(model: T) where T: Fly`. What you have typed is for subclassing I believe. But still it shows same error.

Comment: @adev Thanks for pointing that out! Yeah still same error thought : (

Comment: Any reason why you are not doing this -> `func fetch(model: Fly)` That will work fine,

Comment: I will be using a library and might need to combine this function with it (unless not necessary but not sure at the moment). Wanted to see ideas as to what I'm doing wrong since I don't have experience with generics

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating with `Fly` object with `Bird` instance

Replace code

```
protocol Fly {
}

class Bird: Fly {
}

func fetch<T: Fly>(model: T) {
    print("Done")
}

let bird: Bird = Bird() // Here is a problem 
fetch(model: bird)
```

Comment: I know about that, but why can't I have this `let bird: Fly = Bird()` and pass that into the function if the function accepts any instance that conforms to `Fly`?

Comment: `Fly`  Protocol  doesn't confirm `Fly` it self . `Bird`  does

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Is there a way then to make the function `fetch` accept any type of type `Fly`? Or that doesn't make sense - not sure?

Comment: You can pass  any class object that  confirms protocol `Fly` as argument.

Comment: `let bird: Fly = Bird()` is perfectly fine. I don't think that is the issue here.

Comment: I just tried following and it works fine. `protocol Fly {
    func done()
}

class Bird: Fly {
    func done() {
        print("done")
    }
}
let bird: Fly = Bird()
bird.done()`

Comment: @adev I need to pass `Bird` into the function `func fetch<T: Fly>(model: T)` which you are not doing

Comment: @adev In this case `func fetch<T: Fly>(model: T)`  is not part of protocol.

Comment: @JEL, I was just showing `let bird: Fly = Bird()` is fine to do. I know this is not your case. So issue is not with that. My understanding is `func fetch<T: Fly>(model: T)` accepts only if `Bird` is subclass of `Fly`. Not if it is implemented from protocol.

Comment: @adev Oh ok, yeah I'm aware that is ok - thank you for mentioning too

Answer (score 2):

> *I set `let bird: Fly = Bird()` to be of type `Fly`, shouldn't it work since the function fetch takes any object that conforms to that
>   protocol?*

The overload resolution of the `fetch(model: bird)` call is done statically at compile time. The `bird` instance has been explicitly annotated to be of *type* `Fly` (which happens to be a protocol which can hold, *dynamically*, instances conforming to it). Since [protocols doesn't conform to themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself), a call to `fetch(model: bird)` will not be eligable to use the constrained generic method `func fetch<T: Fly>(model: T)`, since the type of `bird`, namely `Fly`, does not fulfill the type constraint `T: Fly`.